# Saving images in Wordpress using Blob and Ajax to display them later in a gallery

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, blob, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to create a website (by using WordPress) where the user can take a picture of a document, which is then uploaded to the server where it is stored and later reviewed by someone (such as a teacher) who can then decide if the picture was taken correctly or not.

I do this by converting the image to a blob object and then sending it to the server using ajax.

Im fairly new to web development so im not really sure 'how to store the image in the WordPress database?' and 'how to view the blob object later as an image again?'.

Here is What if done so far:

HTML:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><video autoplay="true" id="video"></video></td>
            <td><canvas id="canvas"></canvas></td>
            <td><button id="btn"> Take Picture </button></td>
            <td><button id="sub"> Einreichen </button></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
//Load jQuery
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

//Define AJAX URL
function myplugin_ajaxurl() {

   echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           var ajaxurl = "' . admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '";
         </script>';
}
add_action('wp_head', 'myplugin_ajaxurl');

//The Javascript    
function add_this_script_footer(){ ?>
    <script>
        
    const video = document.querySelector('#video')
    const btn = document.querySelector('#btn')
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas')
    const submit = document.querySelector('#sub')
    const photo = document.querySelector('#photo')
    var base64;
    
         function getBase64Image(img) {
             canvas.width = 500;
             canvas.height = 600;
    
             var pht = canvas.getContext("2d");
             pht.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
             canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {        // get content as JPEG blob
                 var img = document.createElement('img');
                 img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                 document.body.appendChild(img);
                 base64 = blob
                }, "image/jpeg", 0.75);
         }
    
        if ('mediaDevices' in navigator && 'getUserMedia' in navigator.mediaDevices) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
                .then(stream => {
                    video.srcObject = stream
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('An error occured while accessing webcam.')
                })
        }
    
        btn.addEventListener('click', () =>{
            getBase64Image(video);
        })
    
    
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // This is the variable we are passing via AJAX
        var formData = new FormData();
        
        // This does the ajax request (The Call).
    
        $( "#sub" ).click(function() {
            formData.append('action', 'example_ajax_request');
            formData.append('file', base64);
          $.ajax({
              url: ajaxurl, // Since WP 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined and points to admin-ajax.php
              type: 'POST',
              data: formData,
              processData: false,
              contentType: false,
              
              success:function(data) {
                  // This outputs the result of the ajax request (The Callback)
                  window.alert(data);
              },
              error: function(errorThrown){
                  window.alert(errorThrown);
              }
          });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php }
    add_action('wp_footer', 'add_this_script_footer');
```

PHP:

```
//The PHP
function example_ajax_request() {
    if ( isset($_POST) ) {
        $file = $_FILES['file'];
        echo $file;
        
        //move the file anywhere HERE
        
        // Now let's return the result to the Javascript function (The Callback)
        //echo $file;
    }
    // Always die in functions echoing AJAX content
   die();
}
// This bit is a special action hook that works with the WordPress AJAX functionality.
add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
```

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about all this code?

Comment: Why don't you store the files in the file system and only keep the filename in the database?

Comment: @NicoHaase "How do i store the image in WordPress?" and "How do i view the blob object later as an image again?"

Comment: @M.Eriksson I don't have any restrictions on where I store them, so if that's easier, I'm good with that. Can you maybe give me some tips on this? (maybe something specific to my case (blob))